# Get data from hasMany/belongsTo laravel elequent relations

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent

I have two models products and image where product can have one or more image and image have one product related to and these are my models

**product model**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable as AuditableTrait;

class Product extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use HasFactory, AuditableTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'description'
    ];

    /**
     * Get all of the comments for the Product
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function images(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

**product migration**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

**image model**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'filename',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the Image
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**image migration**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
}
```

i made a productController to manage data, but i don't get the full response i only get each table data not with the relation included in the response

I am using laravel 8x

## edits

*productController php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Product::with('images')->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: how you call the relation ? post your controller code

Comment: @Espresso i edited the post buy adding the controller, I want to store data how will a be sending data with the api request

Comment: Probably your product has no images, are you getting null images?

Answer (score 1):

In Product model:

```
public function image()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Image::class, 'pro_id');
}
```

In Image model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(product::class, 'pro_id');
}
```

In controller:

```
$img = product::find($id)->image->filename;
```

Make sure there is a record for the product in the image table. Otherwise you have to manage the errors.

Comment: i managed that, how about I want to add one product ? I failed at this, and docs did not really helps me

Comment: If you query to a record that is not in the table, it returns an error (Trying to get the property from a non-object). Either add an image to the product or manage the lack of image with the `is_null()` method. (`is_null(product::find($id)->image)` )